# git clone - Issue with whitspace within URL

Tags: git, whitespace, git-clone

I am having issues using `git clone` with repositories that have whitespace in their names.

For example, my project name in AzureDevOps is: "TestProject - Test" and the URL to clone my git repo is:

```
git clone --mirror https://xxxPAT@dev.azure.com/organizationname/"TestProject - Test"/_git/"TestProject - Test"
```

However, if I leave the URL like this, git throws an error saying "repository not found" as it only recognizes the URL until the first whitespace.

If I put the repository name in double or single quotation marks, I get "URL using bad/illegal format or missing URL" error.

I have also tried to escape the whitespace with `%20`, as suggested by Google:

```
.../organizationname/TestProject%20-%20Test/_git/TestProject%20-%20Test
```

But git resolves the URL as `/organizationname/TestProject0-0Test/_git/TestProject0-0Test`, making it unable to find the project as it doesn't exist with a zero character instead of the whitespace.

Does anyone have an idea how to solve this issue? Thank you in advance.

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Comment: `%2` being replaced might be some sort of shell argument replacing. Without further information I would suggest trying `%%20` to escape the %-sign.

Comment: Put the entire URL in quotes, not just the URL parts with spaces. So: `git clone --mirror "https://xxxPAT@dev.azure.com/organizationname/TestProject - Test/_git/TestProject - Test"`

Comment: @SebDieBln: Thank you very much the second "%" did the job!

Comment: @LKo.exp I'm glad I could help. I posted the solution that worked for you as an answer. If you set it to "accepted" other people can easily see that this question has a working solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `%2` being replaced by `0` might be some sort of shell argument replacing, depending on what operating system you are using. Without further information I would suggest trying `%%20` to escape the %-sign.